# Flutter: How to use HapticFeedback for Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How to use HapticFeedback in android devices, now on iOS working without problem, but on android not..

Answer (score 0):

Go to AndroidManifest and add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`